# Could not find the source association(s) :character in model Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have two models called User and Relations. Relation stores the relationships between users, and there are different types of relationships. At the moment, I am trying to implement two types: friends and friend requests.

Here are my class associations:

```
class Relation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User"
  validates :owner, presence: true
  validates :character, presence: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :characters, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :relations, foreign_key: "owner", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :friends, -> { where reltype: "friend" }, through: :relations, source: "character"

  has_many :reverse_relations, foreign_key: "character", class_name: "Relation", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :friend_requests, -> { where reltype: "freq" }, through: :reverse_relations, source: :owner

  .
  .
  .
end
```

In IRB, I am trying to use the User.friends array this is supposed to generate, and this error is thrown:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.0)
irb(main):001:0> user = User.find(1)
  User Load (12.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> #<User id: 1, name: "melv", email: "melv@mx.org", password_digest: "$2a$10$g3FjyVP9ya/L.j1iWAzYH.YFOjYOyxUGp3KIt6ajic
Jf...", verified: nil, reg_ip: nil, last_ip: nil, character_limit: 3, characters: nil, created_at: "2013-10-31 19:10:36"
, updated_at: "2013-11-02 11:05:14", remember_token: "4e883d6ec84b5c142882cc084c14bc101a06350f", playchar: 0>
irb(main):002:0> user.friends
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the source association(s) :character in model
 Relation. Try 'has_many :friends, :through => :relations, :source => <name>'. Is it one of :owner?
        <...stack trace...>
irb(main):003:0>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

---

My schema, as requested:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20131102102750) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "characters", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "accountid"
    t.string   "username"
    t.integer  "roundles"
    t.integer  "gems"
    t.integer  "rank"
    t.integer  "tier"
    t.datetime "tiertime"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "permission_ranks", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "label"
    t.integer  "badge"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "relations", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "owner"
    t.integer  "character"
    t.string   "reltype"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "relations", ["character"], name: "index_relations_on_character", using: :btree
  add_index "relations", ["owner", "character"], name: "index_relations_on_owner_and_character", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "relations", ["owner"], name: "index_relations_on_owner", using: :btree

  create_table "tickets", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "desc"
    t.integer  "sender"
    t.integer  "assigned"
    t.text     "addinfo"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.boolean  "verified"
    t.string   "reg_ip"
    t.string   "last_ip"
    t.integer  "character_limit"
    t.integer  "characters"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "remember_token"
    t.integer  "playchar"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["name"], name: "index_users_on_name", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["remember_token"], name: "index_users_on_remember_token", using: :btree

end
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but shouldn't it read `has_many :relations, foreign_key: "owner_id"` in the `User` class?

Comment: Post Your table schema, You messed up something with Your column names.

Comment: Check if this typo is also in your code: `freind_requests`

Comment: @jcm i dont have a field called owner_id

Comment: @TheChamp yes that was a typo thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I think the problem is with naming. It's not a good idea naming association and column with same name. If it's possible start with renaming columns on relation:

```
owner     => owner_id
character => character_id
```

Alternatively You can rename associations:

```
owner     => user_owner
character => user_character
```

Another thing that I see is Your separate characters table. You seem like want to reference characters table from Your Relation model (correct me if I am wrong), but never do it.

```
belongs_to :user_character, foreign_key: "character"
```

Now to Your main question. If I understood Your correctly You want to get list of characters, using friends association defined in User. In this case the line should look like this:

```
has_many :friends, -> { where reltype: "friend" }, through: :relations, source: "user_character", class_name: "Character"
```

**UPDATED**

Author explained that he really wants to reference User model through `friends` association.

```
# relation.rb
belongs_to :user_character, foreign_key: "character", class_name: "User"

# user.rb
has_many :friends, -> { where reltype: "friend" }, through: :relations, source: "user_character"
```

**UPDATE2**

There was a problem with association condition, in particular case You need to specify table explicitly:

```
has_many :friends, -> { where("relations.reltype" => "friend") }, through: :relations, source: "user_character"
```

Comment: I dont want to reference my characters table, thatsfor a separate feature. I will try renaming the table columns.

Comment: Then please explain which model Your `friends`, `reversed_relations`, `friend_ requests` associations are referencing. Your intent is completely unclear.

Comment: `reversed_relations` references the Relation model, the rest reference  the User model

Comment: OK, then why in Your `friends` association You use `character` as the source, what You are trying to achieve with that ?

Comment: Doesn't source reference the field in the Relation table? Or does it reference a class?

Comment: It should reference an `association`. That's why I assumed You want to target characters table. Do You want to target User class instead where character refers to User id? ( relations.character = user.id )

Comment: Yes, thats what I want to do.

Comment: That didn't work, and I don't think I've explained my intention properly, and I', really sorry about that: If I execute `@user = User.find(<id>)` then `@user.friends` should list all users that are friends with `@user`. the Owner field in Relation has the id number of `@user` and the Character field has the id number of the friend. I hope that clears things up.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40424/discussion-between-edgars-jekabsons-and-guilmon)